# Check Contract Compatibility

Tags: contract-development, contract-invocation, data-types

I have a function in one contract that that takes a different user defined contract as the parameter and then does something with it. When I make an RPC call externally I can provide virtually any address as the parameter regardless if it matches the contract interface of my user defined contract type. I'm assuming this is by design since I think in the ABI user defined types just become address.

Example:

```
contract MyContract is MyParentContract {
   string private foo;

   function MyContract(string _foo) {
       foo = _foo;
   }

   function getFoo() public returns (string) {
       return foo;
   }
}

contract ExternalContract {
    MyParentContract private myParentContract;

    function ExternalContract(MyParentContract _myParentContract) {
        myParentContract = _myParentContract;
    }

    function setMyParentContract(MyParentContract _myParentContract) external {
        myParentContract = _myParentContract;
    }
}
```

If I am to send a transaction to ExternalContract.setTestParentContract() I can provide the address of any contract regardless of whether it is a MyParentContract contract or even matches the interface of that contract.

I am wondering if anyone has come up with a solution to disallow incompatible contracts? Or if there are solidity/ethereum changes in the works to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It's by design.

It's possible to check make arrangements to check compatibility before doing something like changing a name registry or owner.

There are a few solutions around. For example: https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/165

We can also imagine a simple system of self-identification. Suppose A wants to be sure it only talks to instances of B; not some random contract lacking the correct interface. Example below.

A caution item: If the "users" who provide the contract addresses are untrusted, then preventing errors won't be enough.

A common pattern is an `onlyOwner` modifier that restricts access to a `changeOwner()` function. The `changeOwner()` function can be further protect itself from admin errors by checking the newOwner for an acceptable response and possibly confirming the admin has control of it; so one can't accidentally transfer ownership out of reach.

Hope it helps.

```
contract A {

  B b;

  event LogIsB(bool allOkay);

  function A() {
    b = new B();
  }

  function doSomething()
    returns(bool success)

{
    // first, check "b" really is a "B"
    if(b.bSig() != sha3("Supports B Interface ver 1")) throw;
    LogIsB(true);
    return true;
  }

}

contract B {

  // Response shows that B is "designed" to produce the expected response.
  // Extremely unlikely this will happen by accident. 
  // There is no assurance that an adversary can't spoof this. 

  function bSig() 
    public
    constant
    returns(bytes32 fingerprint) 
  {
        return sha3("Supports B Interface ver 1");
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! The link to the discussion on interfaces is very helpful and I appreciate the simple example.